# mongoose save to 2 collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello guys i really need help for this one . It's been bugging me for how many days

**model/user.js**

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
username:{
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    index:true
},
password:{
    type:String
},
email:{
    type:String,
    required: true
    // unique: true
},
authToken:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
IsAuthenticated:{
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
},
name:{
    type:String
},
field:{
    type:String
},
e_money:{
    type:Number //this is the integer form in mongoose
}
});


//accesible variable from the outside
var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);

var InfoUser = module.exports = mongoose.model('infouser', UserSchema);
```

**and how i save is like this**

```
var User = require('../models/user);

 var newUser = new User({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        authToken: authToken,
        IsAuthenticated: false,
        username: username,
        password: password,
        field: field,
        e_money: e_money //temporary emoney

    });

 var newUser2 = new InfoUser({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        authToken: authToken,
        IsAuthenticated: false,
        username: username,
        password: password,
        field: field,
        e_money: e_money //temporary emoney

    });




        //save the newly created user to database
    User.createUser(newUser,function(err, user){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(user);
   )};

   User.createUser(newUser2,function(err,user){
    if(err) throw err;
        console.log(user);
   )};
```

What is the problem it always says that the infouser is not defined. Can someone plase

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are exporting two different models through the same `module.exports`. Instead I would recommend that you export them separately:

**model/user.js**

```
// You can add instance methods like this:
UserSchema.methods.createUser = function(user) {
  // Whatever you want to do here
};

var User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
var InfoUser = mongoose.model('infouser', UserSchema);

exports.User = User;
exports.InfoUser = InfoUser;

/*
  You could also do this as:
  module.exports = { User: User, InfoUser: InfoUser };
*/
```

Then when you want to use them:

```
var User = require('../models/user').User;
var InfoUser = require('../models/user').InfoUser;
```

Comment: can't i just export it like this
```var InfoUser = module.exports = mongoose.model('infouser', UserSchema);``` what's the difference?

Comment: The problem is that `module.exports` is exporting only one object (that is how it works), but you are trying to use it twice. You can either use named exports (the first part of my example), export an object with the models as properties of the object (my commented example), or separate them into different files.

Comment: it says InfoUser.createUser is not a function :(

Comment: Yes, createUser is not a default function from mongoose. See my edit to see how to add instance methods (like createUser). If you just want to save the instance to the database I would just use the `.save()` instead, so it would be like `newUser.save()`

Comment: now it says cannot read property 'createUser' of Undefined . i did it like this ```InfoUser.methods.createUser(newUser2,function(err, user){
   if(err) throw err;
   console.log(user);
   });
   //save the newly created user to database
  User.methods.createUser(newUser,function(err, user){
   if(err) throw err;
   console.log(user);```